# Ubuntu 15.10 Wifi Hotspot

Tags: networking, network-manager

As of now i can only create Access Point (AP) wifi networks with open security.
I want to add WPA protection to this hotspot.
However whenever i try  add this the option is always greyed out.
I have tried both nm-connection-editor and kde5-connection-editor.
Using them i can succesfully create AP networks.
Im attaching an image to show the problem.
I have also tried with the same superuser priveleges.Please note that the options save (in network-manager) and ok in kde are greyed out.

[image]

[image]

[image]
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with the built-in `network-manager` based Hotspot since a long time, both related to compatibility and security. For instance, Android phones are able to connect only to Infrastructure APs which `network-manager` doesn't support out of the box (as you pointed out). That's the reason I've written my own Wifi Hotspot in python called `hotspotd`. Feel free to explore and use it:

[Hotspotd](https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd)

Comment: Thanks.I m trying to connect a window phone. The terminal says that hotspot is running. However the network never shows up when i search for it in my Windows Phone.